# Can't install APK from browser downloads

Tags: android

I've downloaded an APK from web, using the default browser and it can't be opened from the Browser -> Downloads.

It tells me "Can't open file"

But I can use a file browser (like OI File Browser) to browse and open this APK, and it works well.

What could be the problem here? Is it about the HTTP header?

Comment: It's a shame this topic is closed, but the tag is wrong. It's not about android programming but a server related thing, which doesn't develop itself alone.

Comment: It's not true, I had to face this problem and it's not a OS thing, even if it would seem to be OS related.
When you start an app download (by code) you have to specify a set of data in order to make the system know it's an installable file, and this is done via code.

Comment: This is end-user software for Android and per the policy of the site should be closed and deleted.

Comment: If agree that it is a programming related question. Because the solution is in the MIME Types of the file served, and the solution is definitively not on the OS.

The solution is to set Content-Type as 'application/vnd.android.package-archive' in file metadatas. It should be the accepted answer because it's the real solution (the other proposed methods are just hacks to make it works). I solved the same problem by setting metadatas.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It shouldn't be HTTP headers if the file has been downloaded successfully and it's the same file that you can open from OI.

A shot in the dark, but could it be that you are not allowing installation from unknown sources, and that OI is somehow bypassing that?

Settings > Applications > Unknown sources...

**Edit**

Answer extracted from comments which worked. Ensure the Content-Type is set to application/vnd.android.package-archive

Comment: I've set up allowing unknown source. 

It looks like the Browser didn't recognize the APK as an APK. I mean, normally, an APK downloaded by browser will have an icon, but this APK doesn't have.

Comment: @Johnny: hmm, perhaps I was too quick to rule out headers, then. What MIME type are you serving the app with? could you post the URL to it, or is it protected?

Comment: thanks for the hint, I used JSP as a proxy for the real APK url, and in JSP I set the ContentType to application/x-download

Comment: @Johnny: alright, try setting it to `application/vnd.android.package-archive`

Comment: @Johnny can you  elaborate  what  header  i  should  add to  make sure  my apk  can be install  directly from notification. its  very curcial  to me since  nexus  devices  among  others  dont have  file  explorer  pre installed on them. if i try and  download apk  from https://zlauncher.com/   i can install  directly . how  do i  achieve this.

Comment: We moved to using a new linux build server to generate apks. We then upload to s3 using the s3cmd command line tool. After the move the apk's couldn't be opened from downloads but did work from a file explorer. To fix it I had to enforce the mime type setting parameter on s3cmd (--mime-type=application/vnd.android.package-archive)

Comment: @DavidHedlund You should put the bit about setting the MIME type into the answer, I nearly missed it in the comments and that turned out to be my problem. (Two devices, both running Android 4.4.4; only one of them recognized `.apk` without the `Content-Type` set correctly.)

Comment: I had same issue, and the problem was with there was space exists in the file name. Removed the spaces and app installation is working fine.

Answer (score 159):

I had this problem. Couldn't install apk via the Downloads app. However opening the apk in a file manager app allowed me to install it fine. Using OI File Manager on stock Nexus 7 4.2.1

Comment: This answer and the accepted answer are actually both culprits. You have to have the "unknown sources" setting on before this solution will work. What's confusing is that on some devices you can use the "Downloads" app to kick off the package installer, but some require that you use something like Astro (an Android file manager app) to kick it off. I have a Nexus 7 running Andriod 6 that works using the "Downloads" app, as does my old S3 running Android 4.4; but my Asus that runs Android 5 requires that I use a file manager, that's the only way I can get a downloaded APK to install. :)

Comment: I think it has something to do with your web browser being a System app. I had this issue with the Chrome browser, but not Chrome Beta. The issue turned out to be Chrome was installed as a System app on my Nexus 6P. I was rooted, so I uninstalled the app via TitaniumBackup, rebooted, and re-installed Chrome from the Play Store. Afterwards, APKs opened normally. Hopefully this helps you!