# Android test APK installation error

Tags: android

I have a sample Android application developed, min 11 - 22. I have built an APK file. I want to send to my tester to test it, so I shared *app-debug.apk* file to him in email. He downloaded in his android device 5.0. Trying to install APK file from Downloads, but it throws error as `"Can't open file"`
How can i share my testing app APK file to another Android device and install it? Please advise.

Comment: If you emailed it to him, he can just click on the APK email attachment and it will install.

Comment: Did you have the correct extension .apk when sending to him?

Comment: It might be the way the email compressed the attachment file that cause the trouble.

Comment: It is not opening, it throws Can't open file after downloading it on the device. In the android studio project->app->build->outputs->apk->there are 3 files such as app-debug-unaligned.apk, app-debug.apk and app-release-unsigned.apk. I don't know which one I should try emailing for installing on other device. But, tried 2 files already app-debug.apk and app-release-unsigned.apk, both of them throwing error as Can't open file.

Comment: I tried sending APK as attachment in Outlook and Yahoo emails.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe old, but for others who might come across this thread. Here's the previous answer from another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/14048742/3621196

Open the apk file using the "File Manager" / "My file" on your phone to install the app.